# how to import DBSCAN labels-Python

Tags: python, pandas, dbscan

I want to include DBSCAN labels as new column in previous Data that I generated using pd.read_csv command. I am running below line.

```
bit_data['DBSCAN']=dbscan.labels_.astype(int)
```

but I am getting this error.

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 bit_data['DBSCAN']=dbscan.labels_.astype(int)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Answer (score 0):

The error is on the *left side*.

That variable `bit_data` probably is an array, and does not allow a *string* index: `bit_data['DBSCAN']`

You probably meant to use a data frame